# How to count session/checkouts in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

jMeter seems to be made to answer the question "how many parallel users can a server handle?"
That of course strongly depends on how fast the users browse the page.
What I would care about is "How many checkouts can the server handle per minute?"

So I've setup a click path that the users follow, from homepage to payment.
I slightly randomize click times (one click every 5-15 s), and use the plugin "jp@gc ultimate thread group" to step up the thread count every minute until the server fails.

What's the best way to get the highest number of checkouts per minute that was reached before the server died? Reporting seems to be all about concurrent users (threads), not taking thread restart i.e. new session into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener which plots throughput for JMeter's [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers). If you're interested in the end-to-end business transaction - you can put all the associated Samplers under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) and tick both `Generate Parent Sample` and `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample` so if you want to measure these "click times" duration of 5-15 seconds as well.

Transactions per Second listener can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)